# Cannot build client_android_javasound from teamspeak sdk

Tags: android, sdk, teamspeak

I'm trying to build a sample app from the teamspeak sdk (client_android_javasound) from https://teamspeak.com/en/downloads/#sdk, using Android Studio but getting errors:

Could not resolve project :soundbackend
Could not resolve project :common

There are 2 folders called soundbackend and common but they are all empty.

I've searched for those 2 modules on google but didn't get the information I was looking for.

Please help.